# Use of LIKE in Oracle with high number of variables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization, sql-like

On Oracle database, I have individual queries which I would like to add based on substitution in the search word. Consider each word can have its word substitution and additional synonym substitution. For instance, the word 4MULA has word substitution such as formula, fourmula. The word VIEW has word substitution such as view, vu and Education has synonyms such as university, college, school

The structure of the where has the following order (3 words):

```
select * 
from dual 
where name like '%4MULA VIEW%' || ' %UNIVERSITY% '
```

Each word has to be substitute by the all possible values to replace it. I have done individual queries, but then I have an excessive amount of queries (about 500 individual queries replacing all possible substitutions). For instance, another individual query would be:

```
select *
from dual
where name like '%FOURMULA VU%' || ' %SCHOOL% '
```

The final number of queries depends on the total number of permutations:

```
FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY
4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY
FOURMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY
FORMULA VU UNIVERSITY
4MULA VU UNIVERSITY
FOURMULA VU UNIVERSITY
...
FOURMULA VU SCHOOL
```

To optimize time I added all possible permutations using OR condition. For instance, I have added as follows:

```
select * 
from dual 
where name like '%4MULA VIEW%' || ' %UNIVERSITY% ' 
      OR name like '%FOURMULA VU%' || ' %SCHOOL% ' 
      ...
      OR name like '%FOURMULA VU%' || ' %SCHOOL '
```

What is the best way to add all permutations in a single query?

Comment: It will be better if you create one table containing all permutation and combination of words and join it with your main table to search it

Comment: In this example what is the criteria to be used that makes  %4MULA VIEW% to be a single search criteria where as %UNIVERSITY% is to be concatenated with a ||

Comment: @George Joseph The name is logically (not physically) divided in company name as the first part such as 4MULA VIEW and the second part is related to the company industry such as University. In database, the name has these two components where I search for all substitutions in company name and all synonym industries. In the most basic scenario, I can have two words, one for the company name such as 4MULA and the second word such as UNIVERSITY.

Comment: @Tejash I have already all permutation and combination of words in a Pandas Dataframe. However, I do not find how to inject them in a single query. Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Instead of inventing your own solution have you considered using [Oracle Text, a built-in free text searching capability, with a Thesaurus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ccapp/working-with-thesaurus-in-oracle-text.html#GUID-05C24323-568D-4952-9358-7C98D68B19BF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object type and collections to create a list of synonyms for each word and then create a user-defined function to handle the substitutions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE wordlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);

CREATE TYPE word_synonyms IS OBJECT(
  word     VARCHAR2(30),
  synonyms wordlist
);

CREATE TYPE word_synonyms_list IS TABLE OF word_synonyms;

CREATE FUNCTION replace_synonyms(
  text         IN VARCHAR2,
  synonym_list IN word_synonyms_list
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  p_text VARCHAR2(4000) := text;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. synonym_list.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. synonym_list(i).synonyms.COUNT LOOP
      p_text := REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  p_text,
                  '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || synonym_list(i).synonyms(j) || '($|[^a-z0-9])',
                  '\1' || synonym_list(i).word || '\2',
                  1,
                  0,
                  'i'
                );
      -- Handle repeated synonyms.
      p_text := REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  p_text,
                  '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || synonym_list(i).synonyms(j) || '($|[^a-z0-9])',
                  '\1' || synonym_list(i).word || '\2',
                  1,
                  0,
                  'i'
                );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN p_text;
END;
/
```

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( text ) AS
SELECT 'FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOURMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FORMULA VU UNIVERSITY'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4MULA VU UNIVERSITY'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOURMULA VU UNIVERSITY'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOURMULA VU SCHOOL'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOURMULAE VULCAN SCHOOLING' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT text,
       replace_synonyms(
         text,
         word_synonyms_list(
           word_synonyms( '4MULA',      wordlist( 'formula', 'fourmula' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'VIEW',       wordlist( 'vu' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'UNIVERSITY', wordlist( 'school' ) )
         )
       ) AS substitutions
FROM   test_data
```

outputs:

> ```
> TEXT                       | SUBSTITUTIONS             
> :------------------------- | :-------------------------
> FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY    | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY      | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> FOURMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY   | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> FORMULA VU UNIVERSITY      | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> 4MULA VU UNIVERSITY        | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> FOURMULA VU UNIVERSITY     | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> FOURMULA VU SCHOOL         | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY     
> FOURMULAE VULCAN SCHOOLING | FOURMULAE VULCAN SCHOOLING
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT text
FROM   test_data
WHERE  replace_synonyms(
         text,
         word_synonyms_list(
           word_synonyms( '4MULA',      wordlist( 'formula', 'fourmula' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'VIEW',       wordlist( 'vu' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'UNIVERSITY', wordlist( 'school' ) )
         )
       )
       LIKE '%4MULA VIEW%%UNIVERSITY%'
```

outputs:

> ```
> | TEXT                     |
> | :----------------------- |
> | FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY  |
> | 4MULA VIEW UNIVERSITY    |
> | FOURMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY |
> | FORMULA VU UNIVERSITY    |
> | 4MULA VU UNIVERSITY      |
> | FOURMULA VU UNIVERSITY   |
> | FOURMULA VU SCHOOL       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a3282cd78d95403010a4f1a4f31e727)*

---

> Currently, in test_data table I'd have just a record such as `FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY`. In addition, I have a table for word substitution and synonyms in very similar fashion you included. Considering I have just the record `FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY` how could I invoke replace_synonyms such as: `SELECT text FROM test_data WHERE replace_synonyms(...)) LIKE '%4MULA VU%%UNIVERSITY%'`. Notice that usually I will want to compare a new name which is not in test_data as the case of `'%4MULA VU%%UNIVERSITY%'`

Swap it round so that the synonyms are normalised in the `LIKE` filter and not in the text in the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( text ) AS
SELECT 'FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY'    FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT text
FROM   test_data
WHERE  text LIKE replace_synonyms(
         '%4MULA VU%%SCHOOL%',
         word_synonyms_list(
           word_synonyms( 'FORMULA',      wordlist( '4mula', 'fourmula' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'VIEW',       wordlist( 'vu' ) ),
           word_synonyms( 'UNIVERSITY', wordlist( 'school' ) )
         )
       )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TEXT                    |
> | :---------------------- |
> | FORMULA VIEW UNIVERSITY |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e18d9183814102ab08a720ee6fba09d0)*

Comment: @JuanPerez Updated

Comment: Thanks MT0, how about if the new word to compare from the query with the like includes words from the wordlist. For instance,  `LIKE '%FORMULA VU%%UNIVERSITY%'` would not retrieve any records while `LIKE '%4MULA VIEW%%UNIVERSITY%'` retrieves all the records.

Comment: @JuanPerez I do not understand what you are trying to achieve; I suggest that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [MRE] detailing what your problem is and include what inputs you are putting into the query and the different outputs you would expect in each case.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help. I would need to include more details

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to build a dataset of the values you would like to search against in a separate table such as company_name(Here i list the possible combination of the base_word and the substitution_values ('4MULA','FOURMULA'),('4MULA','FORMULA') etc

In the next block industry. The values for the industry are listed and the corresponding substituion values.

After that i am perforing a concatenation of the possible permutations between company_name and industry by the join of a.base_word <> b.base_word

Next step is a catersian product with the industry block.

After this the data in the block concat_string contains the possible values that would make up my 'LIKE' condition.

Then i go on to use the LIKE in the main table condition as name LIKE

```
with company_name
  as (select '4MULA' as base_word,'FOURMULA' as substitution_val from dual union all
      select '4MULA','FORMULA'  from dual union all
      select 'VIEW' ,'VU'       from dual union all
      select 'VIEW' ,'view'     from dual union all
      select 'VIEW' ,'VIEW'     from dual 
      ) 
    ,industry
     as (
         select 'Education' as base_word, 'UNIVERSITY' as name from dual union all
         select 'Education' as base_word, 'SCHOOL'    from dual union all
         select 'Education' as base_word, 'COLLEGE' from dual 

        )
     ,concat_string
      as (
select '%'||a.substitution_val||'%'||b.substitution_val||'%'||'%'||c.name||'%' as concat_val
       --,a.*
      -- ,b.*
  from company_name a
  join company_name b 
    on a.base_word <> b.base_word
  join industry c
    on 1=1
        )
  select *
    from dual a
    join concat_string b
      on 1=1
    where 'FORMULA VIEW SCHOOL' like b.concat_val
```

Adding the db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bfcc5f4844503979475af2e1a1b3f062